# Vimeo: how can i track what my registered users (with user_id) are watching on?

Tags: api, vimeo, embedding

I currently have a "Netflix style" video website.
I'm going to move all the videos on Vimeo and embedding it on my website, where all users are registered and logged.

Every user have a unique user_id
Considering I'll embed videos from Vimeo, how can I know (using APIs, I suppose)

- which videos watched user X
- how long user X watched that video

I mean, instead of embedding this
https://player.vimeo.com/video/530618353

is it possibile to embed something like that?
https://player.vimeo.com/video/530618353?user_id=123456

and then download what every single user whatched and how long he do it?

Vimeo stats show "how many" and "how long" the sum of users watched a video. But I need to know what every single user watched.
For example, with this data I want to know the list of "top users" which are watching a lot of hours monthly.

Thanks
Matteo

Answer (score -1):

Ya you can use Google Analytics for that.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).